# Retornar uma unica linha onde atualmente retorna 2 ou mais

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

Estou tentando trazer um dado, porem ele duplica quando tento fazer. Ele faz duplicada se o `PARC_COD` for o mesmo, mas deveria trazer somente a soma da coluna valor da devolução em uma linha indiferente do que tiver ao lado. Só preciso de uma coluna.

Segue exemplo de como esta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o resultado dentro de um `left join`

Preciso que some o valor da devolução para trazer em somente uma linha sem duplicados.

Comment: Qual o critério par trazer uma linha ? o maior ? o mais recente ? agrupado por linha , pivoteado ?

Comment: Ola preciso que o valor da devolução seja somado porque se VC observar ele está exibindo 2x o valor de 1502 e não é se não o relatório fica errado. Aí não estou conseguindo

Comment: Há duas notas de devolução para o mesmo conjunto de dados. Acrescente o código SQL e poste informações sobre as tabelas envolvidas. Caso contrário, não há como ajudar. // Informe também qual é o gerenciador de banco de dados (MySQL, Oracle Database, SQL Server etc)

Comment: Seria em tese um GROUP BY com SUM.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
                                  PARCEIROID
                                ,NFFE_VAL_MER =SUM(NFFE_VAL_MER)
                                 FROM TSTQ_NFFENT 
                                 WHERE  
    CONVERT(CHAR(08),NFFE_DAT_ENT,112 ) BETWEEN @vDATA_INI AND @vDATA_FIM 
                                      AND  STNE_COD =4 
                                        AND NFFE_SER <> 'CAN'  
                                        AND NFFE_CHR_ESPDOC ='NFE' 

                                        GROUP BY  PARCEIROID --estava errando aqui  onde estava adicionando  as 2 colunas na subquery e só precisava adicionar o `PARCEIROID` para conseguir retorno de uma linha
```